# Cython object rich comparison issue

Tags: python, cython

I've been trying to resolve an issue with Cython comparison operators to no avail. Browsed the internet for an hour but there simply not enough literatures that clearly explain how to use rich comparison.

Essentially, I have two Cython Fractions objects in the form Frac(num_value, denom_value) and I want to apply comparison operators.

Here's snippet of the code I managed to work out thus far:

```
cdef class Fraction:

    cdef int _numerator, _denominator, numerator, denominator, a, b

    def __cinit__(self, numerator=0, denominator=None, bint _normalize=True):
        self._numerator = numerator
        self._denominator = denominator

def __richcmp__(a, b, int op):
    a, b = b, a
    if op == Py_EQ:
        return (<Fraction>a)._eq(b)
    elif op == Py_NE:
        result = (<Fraction>a)._eq(b)
        return NotImplemented if result is NotImplemented else not result
    elif op == Py_LT:
        pyop = operator.ge
    elif op == Py_GT:
        pyop = operator.le
    elif op == Py_LE:
        pyop = operator.gt
    elif op == Py_GE:
        pyop = operator.lt
    else:
        return NotImplemented
    return (<Fraction>a)._richcmp(b, pyop)

@cython.final   
def _eq(a, b):
    return (a._numerator == (<Fraction>b)._numerator and a._denominator == (<Fraction>b)._denominator)

@cython.final
cdef _richcmp(self, other, op):
    """Helper for comparison operators, for internal use only.
    Implement comparison between a Rational instance `self`, and
    either another Rational instance or a float `other`.  If
    `other` is not a Rational instance or a float, return
    NotImplemented. `op` should be one of the six standard
    comparison operators.
    """
    # convert other to a Rational instance where reasonable.
    if isinstance(other, (Fraction, Rational)):
        return op(self._numerator * other.denominator,
                  self._denominator * other.numerator)
    return NotImplemented
```

When I apply any any comparison operators on two fractions objects, i.e. frac1 > frac2, I get an error saying:

> TypeError: unorderable types:
>   _cython_magic_d905ad77d87531ef60e3cc8a19beacbf.Fraction() < _cython_magic_bfbf1ca60faa3fc67aa19e16de034078.Fraction()

But this error is utterly useless and I have no clue what is really causing an issue here.

Now if I do equal operator, then the error becomes:

> AttributeError: '_cython_magic_bfbf1ca60faa3fc67aa19e16de034078.Fra'
>   object has no attribute '_eq'

Slightly better, but I don't know why Cython is not able to recognize that _eq is already an attribute inside the Fraction object.

Comment: You `cdef`ed `numerator`, `denominator`, `a`, and `b`, but you never assigned anything to those fields.

Comment: Also, is this your real indentation? If it is, your class doesn't actually have `__richcmp__`. If it isn't your real indentation, here's a quick guide to formatting your code on Stack Overflow: starting on an empty line, paste your code into the question box, then select everything you just pasted (regardless of whether some of it looks okay in the preview) and hit either Ctrl-K or the button with the brackets.

Comment: Why did you do `a, b = b, a` in your `__richcmp__`?